# The present perfect & the phrase "As far as I understand"

Tags: present-perfect

Can anyone tell me why is not the Present Perfect tense used in the phrase "*as far as I understand / understood*" (I guess both are possible, correct me if I am wrong)?

- This phrase means that I understood something in the past, and I still understand it now, so it refers to an interval of time up to now.
- The fact that someone understood something is much more important than when or where it was done.
- It has strong connection to the present: something, happening at the moment of speech, probably depends on whether someone understood / understands something or not.

And yet it seems that nobody says "*as far as I have understood*". Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say "as far as I understand" to mean my present, and possibly previous, understanding.

I would say "as far as I understood" to refer to a specific event in the past, when my understanding was possibly incorrect.

But I would not say "as far as I have understood." Why? Because it is not idiomatic.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, you don't think the present perfect **have understood** combines with **as far as**.  Do you have any thoughts about why that combination is unidiomatic?

Comment: Because it doesn't sound right. The tense is unrelated to the use of "as far as" which as I see it refers to the extend of the understanding, the knowledge that was available, not when it ocurred.